# Optional catch in javascript promises

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, es6-promise

The following is valid:

```
new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      reject()
    })
    .then(() => {})
    .catch(() => {})
```

But I might not always care about the error. Is there a way to make the catch optional?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
new Promise<void>((resolve, reject?) => {
      if (reject) reject()
    })
    .then(() => {})
```

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): undefined`

Comment: What is stopping you from not calling `catch` ?

Comment: When you try to reject a promise it will need a `catch` unless the promise always return a `resolve`.

Comment: Promise constructors will *always* be passed a resolve and reject method - if you dont' want to catch, then don't `.catch(....)`

Comment: If I run the second example I get `Error: Uncaught (in promise): undefined`

Comment: The catch *is* optional, as long as you don't care about the uncaught error that will happen if your promise calls reject.

Comment: Well, you had unhandled promise rejection.  It's right for the javascript engine to tell you when that happens.  It depends on what you mean by 'I don't care about the error'.  Do you want to terminate the process or silently ignore the error.  If you want to silently ignore the error, consider not calling reject in the first place -- or catch and eat the exception like in your first snippet.

Comment: ok, so I guess the best solution would be to create a new wrapper promise that catches but doesn't re-reject. It just resolves in the then.

Comment: I was trying to do this for getting/maintaining a user session (refreshing in the promise) and there are places where if the session is available do something, but if it isn't I don't care (the then block is skipped)

Comment: I just find it silly to place this: `.catch(() => {})` all over the place

Comment: Maybe rejecting the promise isn't the correct thing to do in that case if you're not planning to catch the error.

Comment: The problem is that sometimes I want to, sometimes I don't

Comment: What's the problem with cathhcing the error. First catch it and then return a resolved promise if the caught error is nothing serious.

Comment: @ovg If you have to do it "all over the place", you most likely are doing something wrong. It's hard to say without seeing your code, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to make the catch optional?

No. If you are using a promise that might error, you need to handle that (or propagate it to your caller).

Of course if you create the promise yourself, rejecting it is optional, and you can choose to never reject your promises so that you won't need to handle any errors. But if there are errors from promises that you are using, and you want to ignore them, you must do so explicitly. Just write

```
somePromise.catch(e => void e);
// or             () => { /* ignore */ }
// or             function ignore() {}
```

Comment: Although not the answer I was hoping for ;) , it is the most accurate for my question.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to solve the same issue, and finally come up with the following promise wrapper:

```js
/**
 * wraps a given promise in a new promise with a default onRejected function,
 * that handles the promise rejection if not other onRejected handler is provided.
 *
 * @param   customPromise      Promise to wrap
 * @param   defaultOnRejected  Default onRejected function
 * @returns wrapped promise
 */
export function promiseWithDefaultOnRejected(customPromise: Promise<any>, defaultOnRejected: (_: any) => any): Promise<any> {

  let hasCatch = false;

  function chain(promise: Promise<any>) {
    const newPromise: Promise<any> = new Promise((res, rej) => {
      return promise.then(
        res,
        function(value) {
          if (hasCatch) {
            rej(value);
          } else {
            defaultOnRejected(value);
          }
        },
      );
    });

    const originalThen = newPromise.then;
    
    // Using `defineProperty` to not overwrite `Promise.prototype.then`
    Object.defineProperty(newPromise, 'then', {
      value: function (onfulfilled: any, onrejected: any) {
        const result: Promise<any> = originalThen.call(newPromise, onfulfilled, onrejected);
        if (typeof onrejected === 'function') {
          hasCatch = true;
          return result;
        } else {
          return chain(result);
        }
      }
    });

    return newPromise;
  }

  return chain(customPromise);
}
```

This function lets you wrap your promises with a `defaultOnRejected` function that will handle the rejected promise if no other handler is provided. For example:

```
const dontCare = promiseWithDefaultOnRejected(Promise.reject("ignored"), () => {});
```

The result promise will never throw an "Unhandled Promise Rejection", and you can use it as follows:

```
dontCare.then(x=>console.log("never happens")).catch(x=>console.log("happens"));
```

or

```
dontCare.then(x=>console.log("never happens"), x=>console.log("happens"));
```

or simply without  `onRejected` handler:

```
dontCare.then(x=>console.log("never happens")).then(x=>console.log("also never happens"));
```

An issue with this util is that it is not working as expected with async/await syntax: you need to propagate and handle the "catch" path as follows:

```
async () => {
  try {
    await promiseWithDefaultOnRejected(Promise.reject("ignored"), () => {})
      .catch((e) => { throw e; });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("happens");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could resolve when the error is something you don't care about. If your catch returns anything other than a rejected promise, the error isn't propagated down the chain.

```js
const ignorableError = new Error("I don't care about this error");

const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reject(ignorableError);
    })
    .then(() => {})
    .catch(error => {
      if(error == ignorableError) {
        console.log("Error ignored");
        return;
      }

      // Do something else...

    });
    
myPromise.then(() => console.log("Success"))
```

Comment: My problem is that I want the user of my promise to **decide** whether of not they want to catch. Presuming you mean that I should do the above for a wrapper that ignores errors (in my case, all of them), this is the closest to my solution so I'll go with this answer

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to resolve my promises when I ignore them like this... I forgot ;)

Comment: No, you don't need to return a fulfilled promise. You just need to not throw and not return a rejected promise. You can in fact simply not return anything.

Comment: @tiagodws just realized that this always runs `.then()` which isn't what I wanted. Is it possible to not run `.then()` when it was caught? what I've experimented with suggests not..

Comment: @ovg I don't understand your use case... you don't want it to throw, but don't want to resolve it either. If you have an error it's a bad practice to just simply ignore or silence it, that's why you are getting `Error: Uncaught (in promise)` in the first place... something went wrong and the engine is just making sure you know about it, but that doesn't mean your application isn't working, just mean that something wasn't properly designed (on your application logic or on the API you are using). Maybe explain your case and we can think about a better solution.

Comment: @tiagodws I slightly misunderstood how promises work. If error are thrown or rejected they must be caught just like a traditional try/catch. I didn't realize this as I thought then and catch were more like callbacks, hence why I was looking to make the catch optional. Therefore what I wanted is impossible.

Comment: I was trying to use promises in an *if* or *if-else* fashion when it should be *try and catch* on error if that makes sense?

Comment: For example `getSession().then(/*the user is logged in*/).catch(/*not logged in*/)` but also just `getSession().then(/*the user is logged in*/)`

Comment: @ovg I'm not sure what it is you want now. You want to have a promise that resolves or ignores errors (in my answer). If you want to optionally add something that will re throw certain errors you can add it in the `.catch` of dontCare. if you want to catch all errors then don't wrap the promise in a dontCare.

Comment: @HMR I think my question is pretty clear, I want an **optional** catch, not an **ignore** catch or not catch **some** errors

Answer (score -1):

Let me try to describe your situation:

You have a service that gets user information and a function called `getUser` that uses that service. When the service fails for any reason then `getUser` does not have a user available. The result of `getUser` is used quite a lot of times in your code with the following situation(s):

1. User is available run a function (block of code).
2. User is not available run a function (block of code).
3. Run a function with the error/reject of the service.

When using `getUser` result you may want to run all 3 functions, a combination of 2 of them or only one.

Current `getUser` returns a Promise and this type does not seem to be suitable for your situation. Mainly because rejecting a promise and not catching it will cause unhandled promise rejection. And because if you want to run code if user is available or not it complicates the functions (they both have to check the result instead of assuming user is or is not available).

Maybe you can try the following code, please be careful making assumptions in the `not available` block, this could be due to any error. For example: it does not mean the user does not exist because it could be a network error.

In the example `getUser` is used but can be any function that returns a promise where you assume `not available` on reject.

```js
const isAvailable = promise => {
  //do not expose NOT_AVAILABLE outside this function
  const NOT_AVAILABLE = {type:"not available"};
  //no uncaught promise rejection errors by VM
  const savePromise = promise.catch(x=>x);
  return {
    available:fn=>
      promise
      .catch(e=>Promise.reject(NOT_AVAILABLE))
      .then(fn)
      .catch(
        e=>
          (e===NOT_AVAILABLE)
            ? undefined//ignore
            : Promise.reject(e)//re throw, error is not from service
      ),
    //call not available with the promise if promise rejects
    notAvailable:fn=>promise.catch(()=>fn(promise)),
    catchError:promise.catch.bind(promise)
  };
}

const service = arg =>
  (arg===1)
    ? Promise.resolve(arg)
    : Promise.reject(arg)

const getUser = arg => isAvailable(service(arg));

var user = getUser(2);
//if service failed available will be skipped
user.available(
  user=>console.log("skipped:",user)
);
//both catch and notAvailable will be called
user.notAvailable(
  arg=>console.log("not available:",arg)
);
user.notAvailable(
  arg=>console.log("still not available:",arg)
);
//not handling catchError does not cause uncaught promise exception
//  but you can inspect the error
// user.catchError(
//   err=>console.log("error is::",err)
// );


var user = getUser(1);
//you can call available on user multiple times
user.available(
  user=>console.log("got user:",user)
);
user.available(
  user=>Promise.resolve(user)
  .then(user=>console.log("still got user:",user))
  .then(x=>Promise.reject("have to catch this one though"))
  .catch(e=>console.log("ok, got error trying to run available block:",e))
);

//showing you can inspect the error
var user = getUser(5);
user.catchError(err=>console.log("error from service:",err));
```

Comment: This is what I would want: ```dontCare(Promise.reject("ignored")).then(x=>console.log("never happens")).catch(x=>console.log("happens"));```

Comment: while still allowing ```dontCare(Promise.reject("ignored")).then(x=>console.log("never happens"))```

Comment: hence, making the catch **optional** for the client ;)

Comment: @Bergi points out that this is not possible. But I could use your solution to create a wrapper and let the client choose if they want a catch-able promise (but this is more bloated than the solution I was looking for in this question)

Comment: @ovg Updated answer, I think a promise is not the right type for what you want to do but maybe the answer can give you some idea of what your options are.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with a boolean promise rather than a void promise. The user will need an if/if-else in their then, but at least I'm not mixing else logic and actual errors in the catch (didn't take that into account). It's easier to reason about and I don't have to create custom exceptions to allow the user to decipher what happened.